# Where should I set the subview frame in ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I set the orientation to the landscape left in RootViewController, but in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, the VC's view bounds isn't rotate. In viewDidAppear, it have a right frame. I don't think it is a good place in viewDidAppear, how should I do?

```
    @implementation RootViewController


    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
    }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;

    }

    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
    }

    #pragma mark - Orientation

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
    {
        return toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    }

    //for iOS 6 or later

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
        return YES;
    }

    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
    }

    @end
```

And the log shows that:

```
    viewDidLoad,x = 0.000000, y = 0.000000,w = 300.000000 h = 480.000000
    viewWillAppear:,x = 0.000000, y = 0.000000,w = 300.000000 h = 480.000000
    viewDidAppear:,x = 0.000000, y = 0.000000,w = 480.000000 h = 300.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the frame after orientation change:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be in this function

> - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews { }

Apple's doc says[image]